# How to insert a value in input field of web document using mechanize

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize

I am a beginner in mechanize. I am trying to insert a value in search field of a webpage using python script and then get results. Its source code contains following similar code

```
<div class="form-search">
    <div class="input-prepend">
    <span class="add-on visible-desktop"><i class="icon-keyboard"></i></span>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Text" class="input-large urdu-text" id="word-search-input">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="word-search-button" autocomplete="off" data-loading-text="<i class='icon-spinner icon-spin icon-large'></i>">Search</button>
</div>
```

From source code, I have found that there is no `form` tag but just a `input` tag and button tag. So I could not use form here. What will be its solution.

Comment: Open your developer tools in your browser and observe the request sent when you type the text in the textbox and click on the 'Search' button. I have a feeling the request sent will be an AJAX request. For example: in Chrome open 'Developer Tools'  and then observe the table in the 'Network' tab.

Comment: This is the origional website http://urdulughat.info/

Comment: This link I think will get you the page you want. `http://urdulughat.info/words/advance-search/name:<your-query>` I'm not really sure as to how are you going to type your query in Urdu though.

Comment: In above case, a number is also attached (generated auto). So it could not be used. Best option is scraping